# My gnuplot histogram is not normalized to 1 but to some other value. Why?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have plotted a histogram using gnuplot, but it is somehow not normalized to 1, but to some other value.

The gnuplot code I am using:

```
n=50
min=0.82166501
max=1.66893753
width=(max-min)/50 
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
plot 'CHbl.dat' u (hist($1,width)):(1.0/(2880144*width)) smooth freq w lines lc rgb"red" title "CH"
```

Here, 2880144 is my number of data points.
The histogram that I get as output:

Why is this happening? How should I normalize it to 1?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that normallizing the area rather than the peak height?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to scale a histogram.
Let's take some random data. You can put the data into x-bins and

**a)** sum up all the y-values in a bin. That's `... :2 smooth frequency`

**b)** sum up all the y-values in a bin and scale it such that the area is `1`. That's `... :2 smooth fnormal`

**c)** count the occurences in a bin. That's `... :(1) smooth frequency`

**d)** sum up all the y-values in a bin and normalize it by the peak. That's `...:($2/STATS_max)`

As Ethan says, normalizing is usually to area=1, i.e. b).
Are you are asking for d)?

**Code:**

```
### Normalized histograms
reset session
set key top left

set samples 10000
set table $Data
    plot [-5:5][-5:5]'+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(rand(0)) w table
unset table

min = -5
max = 5
width = (max-min)/50.
bin(x) = width*floor(x/width)

set multiplot layout 2,2
    plot $Data u (bin($1)):2 smooth frequency w boxes lc rgb "red" title "smooth frequency"
    plot $Data u (bin($1)):2 smooth fnormal w boxes lc rgb "web-green" t "smooth fnormal"
    plot $Data u (bin($1)):(1) smooth frequency w boxes lc rgb "web-blue" t "occurrences per bin"

    set table $FindMax
        plot $Data u (bin($1)):2 smooth frequency
    unset table
    stats $FindMax u 2 nooutput
    plot $Data u (bin($1)):($2/STATS_max) smooth frequency w boxes lc rgb "magenta" t "normalized max to 1"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]